# given that ${\log_9 p} = {\log_{12} q} = \log_{16}(p+q)$ find the value of $q/p$

Tags: logarithms

This is not homework, it's just a brain teaser which I can't solve, just some hints should be sufficient, I know that from this we get:
$$ (1/4)\log_2(p+q) = (1/2)\log_3 p  = \frac{\log_3 q}{1+2\log_3 2} $$
now I'd like to combine these quantities in some way so I can see the value of $q/p$ from this, but I can't seem to be able to figure it out.

Comment: Does $\,^{3}\log(n) = \log_{3}(n)$ in your question? Where $\log_{3}(n)$ is log base 3?

Comment: When you write \text{log}p you see $\text{log}p$ with no space between $\log$ and $p$, but when you write \log p, then you see $\log p$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for the confusion in notation, I'll change it

Comment: + thanks, you're right that's very pretty :)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there is a number $x$ such that $9^{x}=p$, $12^x=q$ and $16^x=p+q$
Therefore $9^x + 12^x = 16^x$
One final hint: $12=3\times 4$

Comment: jej, got it if the answer is (1/2)(1+\sqrt{5})! Thanks mate, I didn't think of using the definition of the logarithm I was just using the rules like $\log ab = \log a + \log b$! Superb hint!

Comment: No problem! I suppose the thing that tipped me off to use something different was the appearance of $p+q$ - logs don't like sums, so I didn't expect the log rules to be especially useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ denote the common logarithmic value.  Thus $p=9^L$, $q=12^L$, and $p+q=16^L$.  Let $r=q/p=12^L/9^L=(4/3)^L$.  Then

$$r^2=(16/9)^L=(p+q)/p=1+r$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Jep, thanks! same response as my response to Daniel Littlewood! :) I'd like to accept both your answers, but since I can only pick one I'm gonna have to go for the other 1 cause he was first, sorry!